# Удаление выбранной строки из БД MySQL через приложение C#

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

Необходимо из приложения, разработанного на C# WinForms, удалить запись из таблицы в БД MySQL и в приложении (используется DataGridView). С этим кодом запись удаляется и из таблицы и из БД, но потом, если вновь добавляется та же запись, то в БД она есть, а в таблице DataGridView - отсутствует. Например: была запись: | 1 | Покупка|. Пользователь ее удалил по ошибке, он вводит данные снова и при нажатии кнопки "Добавить", запись добавится только в БД, в DGV ее не будет. Однако, если приложение перезапустить - запись подтягивается из БД.

```
MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand();
sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
sqlConn.Open();
sqlCmd.CommandText = "Delete from operation where кодОперации=" + кодОперацииTextBox.Text + "";
sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConn.Close();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in operationDataGridView.SelectedRows)
{
    operationDataGridView.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Код кнопки Добавить:

```
private void buttonDobavit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=Password;database=ra";

    try
    {
        sqlConn.Open();

        sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO ra.operation (КодОперации, НазвОпер)" +
            "values('" +  кодОперацииTextBox.Text + "' , '" + назвОперTextBox.Text + "' )";

        sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn);
        sqlRd = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        sqlConn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConn.Close();
    }

    upLoadData();
}
```

```
private void upLoadData()
{
    sqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=Password;database=ra";
    sqlConn.Open();
    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ra.operation";
    sqlRd = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    sqlDt.Load(sqlRd);
    sqlRd.Close();
    sqlConn.Close();
    operationDataGridView.DataSource = sqlDt;
}
```

Comment: Не используйте кириллицу в названиях переменных, классов и членов класса. Такой код легко читать только разработчикам 1С.

Comment: if (sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1) выполняется? Исключения не возникает? КодОперации - ключевое поле?

Comment: да, выполняется. Исключения не возникает. КодОперации - ключевое поле

Comment: У вас не работает код добавления, но вы его не показываете. OK.

Comment: Кнопка Добавить работает. Код добавил

Comment: После того, как вставили данные в таблицу, нужно их обновить в гриде. / Метод `upLoadData()` что делает?

Comment: Не пишите код в комментариях. Всю необходимую информацию помещайте в вопрос. Его можно редактировать.

Comment: В однм месте `operationDataGridView`, в другом - `typeobjektDataGridView`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, уже подправил, но все равно ситуация сохранилась. Как исправить - не нашел. Мб еще какие-то советы есть?

Comment: `ra.operation` - что такое "ra"? И почему в запросе delete используется просто `operation`?

Comment: ra - БД. operation - сущность в этой БД.